# Strange difference between HTML and SVG span rendering in Safari

Tags: html, safari, svg

This question is a little specific and I am hoping someone here can shed some light on a potential solution for me.

All of the following points are important:

- I am writing some HTML pages that are going to be read on a third party hand-held device.
- In order to fit the requirements of this device each word must be in a separate span, this is for an upcoming feature of the device that I am not allowed to go into, but it has to be formatted like this.
- This HTML is being converted from SVG, the SVG is created from Adobe Illustrator documents.
- The only place I have any control of the creation of the HTML is in the conversion from SVG to HTML.

My problem is this, in SVG text is broken down into "text" nodes and tspan nodes.  Look at this simple SVG, note how I am changing the Y coord on the first tspan.

```
<text><tspan y="50">Hello</tspan><tspan> World</tspan></text>
```

When this renders in a webkit based browser, like safari, the sentence "Hello World" is displayed with the word "World" right next to the word "Hello".

In my converted HTML example:

```
<div><span style="position:absolute;top:50px;">Hello</span><span> World</span></div>
```

"Hello" is displayed with a y offset of 50, however "World" is displayed in the top left corner origin of the page.

This is frustrating as I do not have the coords of where the "World" span should be placed in the SVG (as Illustrator does not need this coord to render it correctly).  Also, there may be one or more tspans in the SVG with altered positions which will prevent me from applying the style to the div.

In short, does anyone know if there is an attribute I can set to place the second span directly after the first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could style the div instead of the span

```
<div style="position:absolute;top=50px;"><span>Hello</span><span> World</span></div>
```

That would keep text-chunks together and positioned relative to each other, but you could still have a span for every single word

Comment: Good answer, however there may be one or more tspan position changes in the div.  I have edited my question.

Comment: To fix that, there's some information missing. First: In what way is their position altered? Relative to other tspans? Second: Do you know the exact changes on the position if it is altered (e.g.: if it is altered you got the x and y or dx and dy)? In that case style the divs and alter with margins on the span.

Answer (score 0):

Have figured this out after trying a bunch of different things.

It is actually very straightforward, however I didn't realise spans could be nested so I am going to let myself off.

```
<div><span style="position:absolute;top:50px;"><span>Hello</span><span> World</span></span></div>
```

The trick is to wrap all the words that need to be grouped together in a span.  Hopefully this helps anyone who is stuck on a similar issue.

Comment: I finally see what you were trying to do. ["I didn't realise spans could be nested"](http://cdn2.knowyourmeme.com/i/000/041/343/original/index.php.png?1267048195).

Comment: Yes, I didn't realise, luckily I have spent my entire programming career without having to piss about with HTML.